# How to process lots of data and be able to filter by various values such as time/date range

Tags: c#, sql, performance, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm about to start a web project that involves a lot of data, a lot of processing of that data as well as having it filterable.

There is too much data and processing to be able to use anything like LINQ, I'm not sure how caching would work as the data changes quite often.

Essentially the database will house user info, user activity, user surveys, user hierarchy, user teams, etc. They will have a dashboard that presents a lot of statistics about surveys and teams and the dashboard has options to filter data by teams, time/date range, etc.

It's the most data I've dealt with and I need it to be efficient as possible. I'm looking for any insights/suggestions on how to progress with this.

Current tech stack is a headless react.js site with a .NET 6 backend and SQL Database.

I've contemplated using a NoSQL database as a layer or having a 'display' table for certain parts of the dashboard so when any key events happen data is processed/updated and stored in that table and then I can pull the data straight out without any processing and just filter by any of the filter attributes.

I'm curious of alternative approaches as this amount of data and processing is completely new to me.

Are there any Azure resources I could utilize, etc.?

Additionally, I have acquired this project so the existing tech stack wont change.

Edit: Lots of data = 10 organisations and growing, each organisation has 7+/- teams each team has 10+/- users. Organisations have the ability to create new teams, add members, create surveys. All this data is going into the database as is, with little processing.
When querying for statistics, the queries are essentially get surveys  for x organisation -> get responses -> responses contain users, topics etc. when querying you can add filters e.g. teams, date range. The growth rate is expected to be quite high as they recently got a lot of investment and are adding new organisations weekly.

Data arrives unmodified and by that I mean if a user answers a survey, the results go straight into the answers table. When querying with entity framework, it currently starts with the Surveys table -> Questions table -> answers table.

I have profiled(Rider dottrace) some of the slower calls and the biggest delay is around the complex queries going to the db(sometimes 3 table joins)

Latency wise I've done a few improvements that have meant requests have gone from 30seconds+/- to less than a second, so ideally max of a around 3 seconds.

Comment: What is your definition of "lots of data" ? how many tables? How many records? What's the growth rate? Whats reasonable minimum latency requirements? 1 minute? 1 hour? How does the data arrive?

Comment: Step one for performance tuning a database is to understand indexes. LINQ could be absolutely fine for your needs. You haven't defined any metrics or done any experiments so it's very premature to think you need cachng or need to change to NoSql (which could be slower depending on what type of data you have)